# How to create see-through-walls shader, similar to shaders in games when a character stands behind a wall

Tags: shaders, transparency

I'm trying to create a shader, that will dissolve a wall on a certain spot (or any object), when I need it to. Here is an example of what I'm trying to do.

[unity shader example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0rEF8A3wF9U)

Here is what I created. It works pretty well when I use it on a plane with no depth or a cube. However, when I use it on more complex objects, some walls become visible. Enabling backface culling solves a lot of issues, but it is still not ideal.

How can I improve the shader so it completely erases all walls that are under the influence of the Empty object?

[image: blender shader]
[image: blender shader example 1]
[image: blender shader example 2]

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to what you're doing you need to go to the shader editor, press N, go to options in the material you want this effect in, and find "Options > Settings > Back Face culling" uncheck.

Comment: That is quite the opposite of what I want. That setting is unchecked by default and the result is bad. I enabled backface culling (as I said in the post above) which helped a lot but it is still not enough.